# Why the figure caption is showing when I haven't added any of them in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

The issue started recently, it wasn't there before so I was thinking if there's anything to do with latest version of Wordpress?
The caption should show only when I have added them. But the caption is showing even when I haven't added any of them. The caption is not from the image title or other. It's the auto-generated caption i.e Page Title X.
If there are five image in a page, then they will have captions Page Title 1, Page Title 2, Page Title 3, Page Title 4, Page Title 5, etc.
Is there any way to stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was a RankMath setting that was enabled to add missing image captions.
Rank Math Pro has "Image Seo" functionality which has the option to add missing alt, title, captions, etc for the images. So, if the image has a null value in the alt, title, or caption, it automatically adds the post name to it.

Comment: You don't need to apologize :) Maybe someone else will find that same issue. Is there a way you can provide more context on that missing config?

Comment: Rank Math Pro has "Image Seo" functionality which has the option to add missing alt, title, captions, etc for the images. So, if the image has a null value in the alt, title, or caption, it automatically adds the post name to it.

Comment: Awesome! Could you please edit the answer to include that? :)